# Query specific Pages

Tags: pages, query

I wonder if someone would know how to query specific pages (not by id), lets say I create a custom field called "product", and I would like to query all pages with that custom field.

Any Help?

Kind Regards :)!

UPDATE:

So far I've found this solution

thank u so much! so far I've found this solution

```
 global $wp_query;
 $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'page' , 'meta_key' => 'product' ) );
 query_posts( $args );

?>
```

and works really cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages
you can query by meta_key , so to query by `product`
custom field, you will do something like this .

```
$args=array(
    'meta_key' => 'product'
);
$pages = get_pages( $args );
```

Comment: thank u so much! so far I've found this solution! I'm updating the post!